# Using EF6 code-first, reference same property name

Tags: c#, entity-framework, properties, mapping

How to reference both ShippingAddressId and BillingAddressId properties in Customer class to Address class which has a diffrent key named AddressId?

Running update-database -verbose causes **error:**

> Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the
>   types 'Project1.Customer' and 'Project1.Address'. The principal end of
>   this association must be explicitly configured using either the
>   relationship fluent API or data annotations.

```
public class Customer
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public int ShippingAddressId { get; set; }
    public int BillingAddressId { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public int AddressId { get; set; }
    public string Line1 { get; set; }
    public string Line2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string StateProvince { get; set; }
    public string Zip{ get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }

    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What if two customers live at the same address? e.g. man, wife, daughter, son etc

Comment: Are you doing any coding to create any references or just relying on default behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Customer
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public virtual Address ShippingAddress { get; set; }
    public int ShippingAddressId { get; set; }

    public virtual Address BillingAddress { get; set; }
    public int BillingAddressId { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public int AddressId { get; set; }
    public string Line1 { get; set; }
    public string Line2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string StateProvince { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Customer> CustomersWhereShipping { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Customer> CustomersWhereBilling { get; set; }
}
```

You alse have to add custom logic to your DbContext:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
        .HasRequired<Address>(c => c.BillingAddress)
        .WithMany(a => a.CustomersWhereBilling)
        .HasForeignKey(c => c.BillingAddressId);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
        .HasRequired<Address>(c => c.ShippingAddress)
        .WithMany(a => a.CustomersWhereShipping)
        .HasForeignKey(c => c.ShippingAddressId);
}
```

Comment: Thank You Szer, That works. I didn't know precedence is highly important over the virtual property.